# How to make images same height as each other when browser window shrinks

Tags: html, css

I have images that vary in height between 309px and 550px. I want them to always be scaled to the same height as each other no matter what size the browser window is.

I use this code for the images:

```html
<img src="image1.jpg" style="max-height:309px;">
<img src="image2.jpg" style="max-height:309px;">
```

When viewed on a large desktop screen this works as I want scaling both image1 and image2 to the same 309px height. However when viewed on a mobile phone (or suitably shrunk browser) image2 (which is actually 550px high) appears taller than image1 (which is 309px high). The images need to scale as the browser is shrunk but still stay the same height as each other.

Is there a way to ensure that all images appear at the same height as each other no matter what the screen size? I do not know in advance which images are 309px and which are 550px (or anything in between).

Answer (score 1):

"The images need to scale as the browser is shrunk but still stay the same height as each other."  Here they scale as the browser height shrinks.  It then equally shrinks the height of your imgs:

JSFiddle (Where you can play with the height: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmqu4xn/

```css
img {
  max-height:309px;  
}


@media screen and (max-height: 309px) and (min-height:200px) {
  img {
      max-height:200px;  
    }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 199px) {
  img {
      max-height:100px;  
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x550">
<img src="http://placehold.it/75x309">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x609">
```

Comment: I can't apply the css to all img tags as I am using other img tags for icons and logos. I tried replacing img in your css with a class instead (.browseImage) and applying that class to the img tags I am trying to affect but it still gives me images of different height when the browser window is shrunk.

Comment: @BillNoble So you mean as your browser shrinks somehow this max-height is not applied and they are not the same height?  What  browser are you using because I don't see that?

Comment: No sorry. Your code works well! It is just when I try to use it it isn't working for me. I have replaced all of your 'img' in the CSS with '.browseImage' and added 'class="browseImage"' to the img tag stuff. Works fine as before on desktop but on mobile (or shrunk desktop) some images are taller than others.

Comment: @BillNoble What Mobile browser so I can try and help.

Comment: I am using Firefox. Given your code works there must be something I am doing wrong. The images I am working with are added to the Owl Carousel that takes HTML and displays it as a slide show. In theory it should be possible to put anything in the HTML, e.g. images I am using, and size it without it being affected by Owl but maybe I am missing something. The Javascript code creating the img entry is ['<img class="browseImage" id="img"'+i+'" src="/assets/img/small/'+image+'" onLoad="this.src='+"'"+'/assets/uploads/files/'+image+"'"+'">'] The CSS is as your but swapping 'img' with '.browseImage'

Comment: @BillNoble You could then just implicitly set their heights using JavaScript/jQuery to see if that resolves the issue.  Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this error so I can only suggest things from here.  Good Luck!

Comment: Yes Craig I appreciate i am not giving enough information really. I will try your Javascript suggestion though as that really ought to fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="image-ccontainer">

       image goes here

  </div><!-- End image container -->
```

**CSS**

```
 .image-container {
       width: 309px;
       height: 550px;
       overflow: hidden; /* Cuts the image to measure
       the given width/height if it's excess */
    }



.image-container img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto; /* Auto height for the image reduces detoriation */
}
```

**Note:** Be sure that the images are taller than the given width for .image-container; if not, you'll make the height of the image in the second CSS same as .image-container.

Comment: I don't want to restrict the image width to 309px

Comment: Change the width of image-container to whatever you want and let the image with be 100% so as for it to take up the width of the image-container.

Comment: Tried your code but it is making the images too tall and too wide when viewed on a mobile

Comment: It takes up the dimensions you gave it, so reduce the dimensions for mobile display and you'll be just fine.